# Alexa skill not responding after uploading data to firesbase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, alexa-skills-kit

I have developed my project in alexa developer console and I have sentto firebase (Firestore), but Alexa is not sending a response after creating the collection in the firebase(firestore).Below is my code:

```
 const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
 const admin1 = require("firebase-admin");
 const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');
 databaseURL="https://alexa-db8fe.firebaseio.com";


admin1.initializeApp({
credential: admin1.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: "https://alexa-db8fe.firebaseio.com"

});

var db = admin1.firestore();

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
       return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
   },
handle(handlerInput) {

    var documentReference = db.collection('menu1').doc('namedoc');

    documentReference.get().then(documentSnapshot=>
        {
           if(documentSnapshot.exists){

            let speakOutput1 =('Document Exists');

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput1)
            .reprompt(speakOutput1)
            .getResponse();
           }
           else{
            let speakOutput2 =('Document does not Exists');

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput2)
            .reprompt(speakOutput2)
            .getResponse();
           }
        });
}};
```

the code `var documentReference = db.collection('menu1').doc('namedoc');` is creating a new collection and a document correctly but the below response "Document exists" is not said by alexa,its saying like There was a problem is executing etcc......
Can anyone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
return documentReference.get().then...
```

Just return the object you return from your callback function. Alexa just doesn't know what to say, because you don't return the response object in the end of `handle` method.